# preventing visual code editor's complain about app prefixing for your Angular components

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Is there a way to tell visual code editor to not to force that famous red underline for those components NOT starting with that recommend "app-" prefix?

I think it makes sense to be able to create a component and call it, `<get-user>` rather than `<app-get-user>`. Especially, when you think about having 100's of components, all starting with `<app-...>` does not make sense.

I understand that that app prefix may provide some sort of a name spacing safe haven (to prevent conflicts with other components ).  But then, I should be able to prefix all my components like `<xyz-...>`, why the forcing as `'?

Answer (score 0):

In the tslint.json file you can set it to whatever prefix you want:

```
"directive-selector": [
  true,
  "attribute",
  "mh",
  "camelCase"
],
"component-selector": [
  true,
  "element",
  "mh",
  "kebab-case"
],
```

In my example above, I set my prefix to "mh" as it is the prefix for my particular application (MovieHunter).

You could also turn this check off entirely by setting the true to false for both of these.

NOTE: If you are using the CLI, you can do:

```
ng new myApp --prefix xyz
```

This sets the prefix automatically to whatever you set this to (xyz in this example) in both the tslint.json file and in the .angular-cli.json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of vs code and also have TS Lint extension installed then it will show you a light bulb when you click on the selector. Click on it to get the option to disable the rule.